# Wie sagt man "I've Heard Some Talk" auf Deutsch?

Tags: usage

I'm trying to translate a poem from English to German, and the missing line is:

> I've heard some talk, they say you think I'm fine.

I've rendered *They say you think I'm fine* as *Man sagt du liebst auch mich.*

But I need something for *I've heard some talk*.

Could I use a construction using the word *Gerücht*?

Comment: I've corrected the German title of your question. In German there is no title case.

Comment: @splattne: Good to know. Danke.

Comment: We say in Austria "das Gemunkel" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My proposal:

> Es gibt Gerüchte, ...

or

> Ich hab davon gehört, ...

An elegant translation for "they say" is "es heißt":

> Es heißt, du glaubst es gehe mir gut.

Comment: @splattne: I thought so. But I had just learned the word "Geruchte," two days ago on this site, and wasn't sure how to use it. Thanks. It now reads..."Es gibt Gerucht', Man sagt du liebst auch mich."

Comment: But "du liebst mich" means "you love me"; that's quite different than "you think I'm fine", isn't it? Or is it *dichterische Freiheit* (poetic license)?

Comment: @splattne: Poetic license. Actually, the slang, "You think I'm fine" is an understated, but parallel construction to "This guy's in love with you" in the song. In another translation, I translated You are my life, my love, my all," as "Du bist mein Leben, meine Liebe, mein SCHATZ." (But the previous line was Sommer und Fruhling, Winter und Herbst.) I thought Schatz rhymed better with Herst, than "alle," as well as being more "German."

Comment: @Tom You *really* have to say what nuance you want to convey. "Es gibt Gerüchte" has a negative touch. And you cannot leave off a final "e" everywhere.

Comment: @Tom: And you also can't leave away the dots over the "ü" of "Gerüchte". They are not just some adornment to the "u", it's really so that "ü" is a different letter. I can guess that it's non-trivial to get an "ü" on your keyboard, but see this meta post: [Wie schreibt man Umlaute und scharfes S auf nichtdeutschen Tastaturen?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/724)

Comment: @thei *Gerüchte* does not necessarily have negative touch. For example: *"Es gibt Gerüchte, dass im Herbst das neue iPhone erscheinen wird."* Though I agree that it's not the most beautiful word to use in a poem.

Comment: @Hendrik: I don't have a machine that allows me to make those "diacritical" marks (I would make them in a handwritten text. But point taken about the e.

Comment: @Tom: None of the methods at that link are of help? What a pity! However, I'd go as far as to say "use copy-and-paste"!

Answer (score 2):

> Es heißt,..

I consider a good approach

There is also

> Man munkelt...

and also one might use

> Sie sagen...

for *I've heard some talk, they say..* which implicates the speaker heard it by someone, somehow. `Sie` does not need to be determined more closely.

Comment: +1 für *munkeln* - rettet die vom Aussterben bedrohten Wörter! :)

Answer (score -3):

> Ich habe gehört. (standard German)

In Tirol, one would say something like

> Ich hob kaeth.

Comment: Are you sure that this is an idiomatic translation?