# Wie gebe ich ẞ (großes ß) auf einer deutschen Tastatur ein?

Tags: capitalization, eszett

Wie gebe ich den Buchstaben ẞ (großes ß) auf einer deutschen Tastatur ein?

Ich stelle die Frage nur, um sie selbst zu beantworten, falls später jemand danach sucht, aber wenn jemand mehr dazu schreiben möchte, zum Beispiel zu anderen Betriebssystemen, sei sie oder er herzlich eingeladen. Das Thema kam im Zusammenhang mit [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73111/how-can-i-type-%E1%BA%9E-upper-case-%C3%9F-with-the-windows-10-us-international-keyboard) auf. Dort ist (auf englisch) auch mehr zum großen ẞ selbst und seinem Einsatz zu finden.

Ein Blogpost mit Argumenten, warum ein großes ẞ statt der Umschreibung mit SS in manchen Fällen sinnvoll ist, findet sich [hier](https://www.typografie.info/3/artikel.htm/wissen/grossbuchstaben-eszett).

Comment: Eigentlich gibt es zu der verlinkten Frage doch schon eine Antwort, die die Frage umfassend beantwortet?

Comment: @tofro: aber da war die Frage doch nach einer amerikanischen Tastaturbelegung? Wie soll man das finden, wenn die Frage dort eine andere ist? Und in deiner Antwort steht "On a typical Windows system, ẞ can be input by pressing <Shift><AltGr>"s", ", was für eine deutsche Tastaturbelegung ja eben nicht zutrifft. Ich habe diese Frage und Antwort eigentlich genau deshalb angelegt, damit man das, was du drüben oben offtopic in einen Kommentar geschrieben hattest, leichter finden kann.

Comment: <Umschalt><s><s> So einfach ist das

Answer (score 3):

Unter Windows mit eingestellter [deutscher Tastaturbelegung](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdgr) erreicht man das große ẞ mit Umschalt+AltGr+ß.

Eine alternative Eingabemöglichkeit, die unter Windows mit allen internationalen Tastaturbelegungen, aber nicht in jeder Software funktioniert, ist, bei gedrückter Alt-Taste den dezimalen Unicode 7838 auf dem Ziffernblock einzugeben. Das funktioniert zum Beispiel in Word und Wordpad, aber in Browsern, im Windows-Editor oder Notepad++ bekommt man damit ein anderes Zeichen. (Hier wird der eigegebende Code modulo 256 genommen.)

In der Windows-Registry kann alternativ auch eine [Methode aktiviert werden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_input), über die man Unicode-Zeichen direkt über die Tastatur als Hexcode eingeben kann. Der hexadezimale Unicode des großen ẞ ist **1E9E**.

Comment: "Unter Windows" gilt für Windows 10. Für Windows 7 und älter definitiv nicht. Windows 8 und 8.1 weiß ich nicht.

Comment: @Bolpat Ja, laut Wikipedia gilt die Tastenkombination Umschalt+AltGr+ß ab Windows 8. Windows 7 ist 2009 erschienen, da war das große ẞ gerade erst seit einem Jahr im Unicode. Die wichtigsten Windows-Schriftarten enthalten es in Windows 7 aber schon, deshalb müsste die Eingabe als Unicode-Zeichen eigentlich schon funktioniert haben. Das wäre aber eher eine Frage für SE Retrocomputing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Auf Geräten mit macOS ist es nicht möglich, das große ẞ über die Tastaturbelegung einzugeben.

Wenn man es nur gelegentlich braucht, holt man es sich am besten per copy&paste von einer Internetseite, die dieses Zeichen enthält (z.B. diese Seite hier, oder [die Wikipediaseite über das große ẞ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F)

Braucht man es öfter, kann man in der Systemeinstellung eine Tastenfolge definieren, mit der man das Zeichen erhält. Am Beispiel von Ventura (macOS 13):

- Apfel-Menü (ganz links oben am Bildschirm)
- Systemeinstellungen ...
- Tastatur
- dort unter Texteingabe: Textersetzungen ...
- auf das + klicken um eine neue Ersetzung zu definieren

Ich habe definiert:

- Ersetzen: !ß
- Mit: ẞ

---

Dank Tofros Kommentar ist mir auch die Möglichkeit der Unicode-Eingabe wieder eingefallen:

Man schreibt einen Text und kommt zu der Stelle, an der man ein großes ẞ eingeben möchte. Dazu drückt man die Tastenkombination **[shift] + [alt] + [cmd]** und aktiviert dadurch die Zeichenübersicht. Dort kann man rechts oben im Suchfeld den Codepoint eines beliebigen Unicode-Zeichens eingeben. Im Fall des großen ẞ ist das dieser Code: **U+1E9E**. (Das führende U und die Hexadezimalziffer E darf man auch kleinschreiben.) Daraufhin erscheint in der Zeichenübersicht das gesucht Zeichen. Da klickt man nun drauf, und schon steht dieses Zeichen and der gewünschten Stelle in dem Dokument, an dem man gerade gearbeitet hat.

Das ist zwar etwas umständlicher als im Betriebssystem Windows, hat aber den Vorteil, dass man das Zeichen sehen kann, bevor man es in den Text einfügt.

Hinweise zu Apple-Tastaturen:

- Die Shift-Taste (deutsch: "Umschalt-Taste") ist auf vielen Tatstaturen mit dem Symbol **⇧** beschriftet.
- Auf Apple-Tastaturen kann die alt-Taste (in Handbüchern oft als "Wahltaste" bezeichnet) unterschiedlich beschriftet sein: **alt, option, opt, ⌥**. Auf sehr alten Tastaturen ist das die Taste mit dem ausgefüllten Apfel-Logo.
- Auch die cmd-Taste ("Befehlstaste") gibt es mit unterschiedlichen Beschriftungen: **command, cmd, ⌘**. Auf sehr alten Tastaturen ist das die Taste mit dem nichtausgefüllten Apfel-Logo.

(Und falls jemand mal die hier angeführten Symbole schreiben möchte, das sind ihre Unicode-Codepoints: ⇧ = U+21E7, ⌥ = U+2325, ⌘ = U+2318. Das letzte Symbol heißt übrigens offiziell *Schleifenquadrat*)

Comment: Zu deinem ersten Satz: Auf MacOS kann man das Zeichen auch über die (mitgelieferte, nur nicht standardmäßig aktivierte) Unicode-Eingabe-Methode eingeben. In den Systemeinstellungen/Tastatur muss die zuerst aktiviert werden, dann kann man mit `<ALT>1e9e<ALT loslassen>` das Zeichen eingeben. Man muß allerdings die Eingabemethode (in der Kopfleiste) immer vorher aktivieren und danach deaktivieren, weil die Unicolde-Eingabemethode gleichzeitig die Tastatur auf US-Belegung umschaltet. Aber: Das funktioniert auch ohne Internetzugang.

Comment: @tofro: Das geht auch ohne auf die US-Belegung umzuschalten. Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend ergänzt.

Answer (score 1):

Unter macOS gibt es mindestens zwei Möglichkeiten zur Eingabe eines grossen ẞ:

1. Die Eingabequelle «Deutsch – Standard» entspricht der [Tastaturbelegung E1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1_(Tastaturbelegung)) (ausgenommen die Extra-Wahltaste). Das grosse ẞ wird mit **Option+G** eingegeben.
2. Die Eingabequelle «Unicode Hex-Eingabe» erlaubt eine Eingabe beliebiger Zeichen aus dem *Basic Multilingual Plane.* Für das grosse ẞ bei gedrückter **Option**-Taste die Sequenz **1E9E** tippen.