# Benutzung von Anführungszeichen

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Immer wieder stolpere ich über die Verwendung der Anführungszeichen in der deutschen Sprache.
Bisher nahm ich immer an, dass diese Variante korrekt sei:

> „Das Beispiel“

Nun ist in der DIN5008 aber unkommentiert auch eine weitere Variante aufgeführt:

> "Ein weiteres Beispiel"

Auf der Internetseite vom [Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/anfuehrungszeichen) wird es ähnlich gehalten: Alle Anführungszeichen werden hier „so“ verwendet, bis auf das erste Beispiel bei Regel 8, wo unkommentiert "so" verwendet wird:

> In dem Wort "Tri"athlon steckt das griechische "tri-" (drei).

Könnt Ihr mir diesen fluktuierenden Gebrauch der Anführungszeichen näher erläutern, eventuell auch in Hinsicht auf die DIN5008?

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/117/1224

Comment: Das zitierte Beispiel hat mich dazu veranlasst, die Frage [Anführungszeichen innerhalb eines Wortes?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9756/1859) zu stellen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die deutschen Anführungszeichen sind kein Teil des ASCII, der eine Schnittmenge fast aller Textenkodierungen ist. Wenn ein deutscher Text im ASCII geschrieben wird, dann werden neutrale, doppelte Hochkommas (`"`=u0022) verwendet, die im ASCII an Stelle 22 (hexadezimal) stehen.

Die DIN5008 legt im Punkt 1 Anwendungsbereich unter anderem fest:

> Diese Norm legt fest, wie durch ein einheitliches Anwenden von Schriftzeichen
>   bei Textverarbeitungssystemen und Schreibmaschinen mit alphanumerischen
>   Tastaturen eine leichte und eindeutige Lesbarkeit der Schrift gesichert werden
>   kann und wie durch entsprechende Gestaltungsvorschriften die Schriftstücke
>   zweckmäßig und übersichtlich gestaltet werden können.

In Anwendungen, in denen die Enkodierung unsicher ist oder die *eindeutige Lesbarkeit* besondere Bedeutung hat (z. B. in Quelltexten), kann es sinnvoll sein, neutrale Hochkommas aus dem ASCII zu verwenden statt der bevorzugten deutschen (`„“`). In ebendiesem Sinn ist auch das Beispiel in der DIN5008 geschrieben worden, was daran zu erkennen ist, dass eine Typewriter-Schriftart verwendet wurde.

Die Verwendung im Duden ist sicherlich ein Fehler, der z. B. dadurch entstanden sein könnte, dass die ursprünglich neutralen Hochkommas automatisch durch deutsche ersetzt worden sind, wobei ein Suchmuster verwendet wurde, dass wortinnere Hochkommas nicht findet.

Comment: Das ist mal eine vernünftige Erklärung. Vielen Dank. Das mit dem Duden habe ich mir auch schon gedacht, aber leider blieben alle meine Kontaktversuche unbeantwortet.

Answer (score 2):

Der lieben Vollständigkeit halber sei auch noch erwähnt, dass im Deutschen *(dies gilt für Deutschland und Österreich, aber nicht für die Schweiz!)* neben den `„Gänsefüßchen“` auch umgekehrte `«Guillemets»`, in diesem Fall `»Chevrons«` oder `»Möwchen«`, verwendet werden können. Je nach Schriftbild ist dies häufig die bessere respektive schönere Wahl, wobei dies natürlich persönlichen Vorlieben geschuldet bleibt. Der geneigte Hobbytypograf möge also frei entscheiden, die alternativen Anführungszeichen aber bitte niemals durch spitze Klammern ersetzen oder sie mit Gänsefüßchen mischen. ;)

> »In dem Wort Triathlon steckt das griechische ›tri‹ (drei)«.

Comment: Im Duden wäre es dann aber: In dem Wort »Tri«-athlon steckt das griechische »tri« (drei). Das sieht dann ziemlich sch**** aus, wenn der Bindestrich und die Spitzen der Guillemets nicht dieselbe Höhe haben.

Comment: Das ist natürlich korrekt, ich hatte das Beispiel nur gewählt, um ein subtiles Beispiel für die zugehörigen halben Anführungszeichen geben zu können.

Comment: @LarsBeck Vielen Dank für die Info. Aber heißt das, dass die *Guillemets* auch in der deutschen Sprache verwendet werden können, oder sind nur die *Chevrons* erlaubt.

Comment: @Tik0 Guillemets werden nur im Schweizer Hochdeutsch verwendet