# Anführungszeichen innerhalb eines Wortes?

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Auf *duden.de* heißt es in einem Beispiel zur [Regel 8](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/anfuehrungszeichen#K8) (die Art der verwendeten Anführungszeichen soll hier keine Rolle spielen, das wird [bereits in einer anderen Frage behandelt](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9586/1859)):

> In dem Wort "Tri"athlon steckt das griechische "tri-" (drei).

Ich war mir ziemlich sicher, dass das nicht erlaubt ist, denn Anführungszeichen sind doch *Satzzeichen*, keine *Wortzeichen*, oder?

Allerdings enthält auch das Regelwerk *Deutsche Rechtschreibung* ein derartiges Beispiel ([PDF](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/fileadmin/service/reform/regeln2006.pdf), Seite 97 (§ 94)):

> Das Wort „fälisch“ ist gebildet in Anlehnung an West„falen“.

Wobei es mit »Wörter oder Wortgruppen, über die man eine Aussage machen will« betitelt ist (und nicht »Wortteile« oder wie man das auch nennen mag).

Ist diese Verwendung also erlaubt oder sind beide Beispiele fehlerhaft?

**Dürfen Anführungszeichen innerhalb eines Wortes stehen?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Zusammenfassung:** Wenn die offiziellen Regeln es als Beispiel nutzen, halten deren Schaffer es wohl für korrekt. Ich halte die angeführten Beispiele dennoch für unsinnig, kann mir aber sinnvolle Beispiele für Anführungszeichen innerhalb des Wortes denken.

---

Wenn überhaupt, dann sind derartige Anführungszeichen durch den von Dir angeführten § 94 der Rechtschreibregeln erlaubt und wegen des expliziten Beispiels (»West„falen”«) ist davon auszugehen, dass sich die Schaffer der Regeln dies auch so gedacht haben, obwohl sie gegen ihre eigene Regel verstoßen, wenn man diese wörtlich nimmt (aber das wäre nicht der erste derartige Widerspruch). Bleibt die Frage, ob das denn wirklich so sinnvoll ist (und ob es weitere Widersprüche gibt).

---

Zunächst **das Beispiel aus dem Rechtschreibregelwerk**:

> Das Wort „fälisch“ ist gebildet in Anlehnung an West„falen“.

Hier gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten, was eigentlich gesagt werden soll:

1. Das Wort, an das angelehnt wird, ist *Westfalen.* In diesem Fall ist das Wort, über das ich eine Aussage machen möchte, *Westfalen* und dieses ist dann gemäß der Regel auch in Anführungszeichen zu setzen:

   > Das Wort „fälisch“ ist gebildet in Anlehnung an „Westfalen“.

   In diesem Fall sollte zwar jeder sehen, welcher Hälfte von *Westfalen fälisch* entstammt, aber in komplexeren Beispielen kann es durchaus sinnvoll sein, Wortteile zu betonen. Das ist dann aber eben eine Betonung und fällt nicht mehr unter den Zuständigkeitsbereich von Anführungszeichen und sollte m. E. daher durch irgendeine andere Weise der Textauszeichnung geschehen.
2. Das Wort, an das angelehnt wird, ist *Falen.* Das aber ist schlichtweg nicht die Aussage des Satzes, denn dort steht ja unmissverständlich, dass an *Westfalen* angelehnt wird. Möchte man dies aussagen, muss man also schreiben:

   > Das Wort „fälisch“ ist gebildet in Anlehnung an „Falen“.

   (und dann vermutlich erklären, was *Falen* ist).

---

Im **Duden-Beispiel** ist die Unsinnigkeit m. E. noch deutlicher:

> In dem Wort "Tri"athlon steckt das griechische "tri-" (drei).

Hier wird ausdrücklich eine Aussage über das Wort *Triathlon* gemacht und also ist dieses komplett in Anführungszeichen zu setzen:

> In dem Wort „Triathlon“ steckt das griechische „tri-“ (drei).

---

Aber nur dass die beiden Beispiele unsinnig sind, heißt ja noch lange nicht, dass dies auf alle Beispiele zutrifft. Zwar kann ich mir kein Beispiel vorstellen, bei dem ich Anführungszeichen gemäß § 94 (3) innerhalb eines Wortes setzen würde, da sie alle an den oben angeführten Gründen scheitern, nämlich dass ich, wenn ich ein Wort komplett schreibe, auch über das ganze Wort eine Aussage treffe. Allerdings gibt es ja noch § 94 (4):

> [Man kann deutlich machen:] Wörter oder Wortgruppen, die man anders als sonst – etwa ironisch oder übertragen – verstanden wissen will

Wenn ich – wie die Verfasser der Regeln ein paar Zeilen vorher – missachte, dass diese Regel Wortteile nicht erfasst, könnte ich z. B. schreiben:

> Er wurde in „Schutz“haft genommen.

Hier kennzeichnen die Anführungszeichen, dass nur das Wort „Schutz“ irreführend ist – der Betroffene wird durchaus inhaftiert.

> Über diese Phasenraum„verklebung“ erreiche ich Folgendes: …

Hier kennzeichnen die Anführungszeichen, dass ich *Verklebung* in Ermangelung eines besseren Wortes nutze und es kein bereits eingeführter Begriff oder ein gängiges Fachwort ist. *Phasenraum* ist hingegen ein gängiger Fachbegriff, weswegen er nicht in Anführungszeichen steht.

In beiden Beispielen wäre es zwar m. E. auch nicht falsch und eventuell sogar schöner, das ganze Wort in Anführungszeichen zu setzen; es entstehen aber auch keine logischen Probleme dadurch, dass nur ein Wortteil in Anführungszeichen steht.

Comment: Zu deinem Schutzhaft-Beispiel: [*belleslettres.eu* schreibt darüber](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/gansefusschen-anfuhrungszeichen.php): »Grammatikalisch und lexikalisch falsch ist der Ge­dan­ke der Teil­ironie. Hier­bei wird bei einem Deter­mina­tiv­kom­posi­tum nur der Be­stand­teil in Anführungs­zei­chen ge­setzt, den man für ironisch hält.«

Comment: @unor: Keines der Beispiele war ironisch gedacht. Ohnehin: Wenn ich die entsprechenden Konstrukte ohne Wortkomposition bauen würde, wäre es demnach wohl in Ordnung, Teile zu kennzeichnen, also z. B. »Haft zum „Schutz”«, »„Verklebung“ von Phasenräumen«? Wieso soll dies nicht mehr gehen, sobald es ein Wort ist (vom logischen Standpunkt – stilistisch ist es zugegebenermaßen suboptimal)? Vielleicht findet sich sogar ein Beispiel, wo es einen deutlichen Unterschied macht, welchen Wortteil man kennzeichnet.

Comment: Ich würde deine Beispiele »Schutz«-Haft (ungerner) oder Phasenraum-»Verklebung« setzen. Dadurch hat man das Problem der Teilanführungszeichen gelöst, indem man die Bestandteile durch einen Bindestrich trennt. Für das Dudenbeispiel wäre **Tri**athlon, für das andere aus der Frage West*falen* oder West**falen** nach meinem Empfinden schönere Lösungen.

Comment: @Jan: Auch Wortteile, die durch Bindestriche getrennt sind, sind immer noch Wortteile. »„Schutz“-Haft« ist also nicht weniger regelwidrig als »„Schutz“haft«. Man kann natürlich darüber streiten, was stilistisch besser ist.

Comment: Das in dem Wort Triathlon das griechische tri (=drei) steckt versteht man auch ganz ohne Anführungszeichen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is used to emphasize the part that the example is referencing to.

For example it's easier to see when you say: 'fälisch' is build from 'west"falen"' than it would be without the ".
In other words: it is used as a substitute for westFALEN (capitalization-emphasizing for the example above)

This is the only case I know where this is correct use 'in-word'.

Comment: Yep. Think of it like saying "This pun is 'pun'tastic!"... Or "S'teuer'n zahlen ist 'teuer'" (paying taxes is expensive).

Comment: @mcwise: I found especially the second example hard to read and it makes me cringe. Anyway, there is no rule allowing quotation marks to be used for general-purpose emphasis.